# Rails reopen class and delete association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Working with a gem (spree), I'd like to reopen a class in the gem and add an association to it and delete one of the existing association, how do I go about delete an association with class_eval? or is it not a good idea to touch the existing model, should I just roll my own model instead?

```
Spree::SomeClass.class_eval do
  # Add a new association
  has_many :foo

  # I want to delete the `has_many :bar` in Spree::SomeClass
  # ???
end
```

Comment: Tell me which model do you want to delete and I will tell you if it's a good idea or not. Generally, it's not a good idea, but I could see some special cases for doing it. You probably want to build your own models & relationships and leave the Spree ones in place.

Comment: @JasonFB I have a `ZonePrice` model which has many `Spree::Price` and `Spree::Variant`. I would like to delete the association between `Spree::Variant` and `Spree::Price`, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to build your own models & relationships and leave the Spree ones in place